# Unexpected symbol when copying strings in C

Tags: c, string, copy

I need to filter from a string non-alpha characters and convert everything to lowercase. I'm using the following:

```
void filter(char orig[], char filtered[]) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; orig[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if(isalpha(orig[i])){
            filtered[i] = tolower(orig[i]);
        }
    }

    return ;
}
```

However, my tests fail because of characters that appear at the end. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must terminate the target string, and you have skipped character positions that were not alpha

```
void filter(char orig[], char filtered[]) {

    int i, j = 0;                               // separate index for filtered[]
    for (i = 0; orig[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        if(isalpha(orig[i])){
            filtered[j++] = tolower(orig[i]);   // inc index
        }
    }
    filtered[j] = '\0';                         // terminate string
    return ;
}
```